# TFS Build Definition use msbuild arguments generate files in staging directory

Tags: asp.net, msbuild, tfsbuild, webdeploy

In the build definition, I have those parameters in the msbuild arguments:
/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=FileSystem /p:PackageLocation=$(build.stagingDirectory)\DeployPackages\ /p:PackageAsSingleFile=false /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:AutoParameterizationWebConfigConnectionStrings=False /p:GenerateProjectSpecificOutputFolder=true

All the files required are place in the DeployPackages folder, but list of folder and subfolder to get to the code is to big. Is there a way to reduce the number of folders?
_work\5\a\DeployPackages\Archive\Content\d_C\tfsbuild_work\5\s\Main\AdService\obj\DEVE\Package\PackageTmp\

and it's the PackageTmp folder that contains the file I need to copy to our server.

thanks

Comment: Which build are you using ？ XAML or Vnext build?

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

To reduce the folder  path and structure you could use other argument instead of $(build.stagingDirectory) in package location. Such as

```
/p:PackageLocation="$(BuildConfiguration)"\DeployPackages\XX.zip
```

or

```
/p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\DeployPackages\XX.zip
```

---

Besides if you got any long path issue, the most effective and easy way still is spending some time **tweaking your file/folder structure.**

*For example:* instead of `\xx\Build\Drop\ProjectName`, just use `\xx\Build\Drop` (or `\xx\Builds`) since the project name is also in the build name.

Comment: I'm using the next build service (vnext).
I would like to go from:
_work\5\a\DeployPackages\Archive\Content\d_C\tfsbuild_work\5\s\Main\AdService\obj\DEVE\Package\PackageTmp\

to this:
_work\5\a\DeployPackages\AdService[it's the project name]\files required placed here

if I change the msbuild argument PackageAsSingleFile=true. It will generate a zip file instead of putting the file in a folder structure but the folder structure in the zip is the same as the other one.

Comment: Suggest you to use `/p:PackageAsSingleFile=true`. Some blog for your reference [How to package a web project for deployment from the command line](https://blogs.endjin.com/2016/10/how-to-package-a-web-project-for-deployment-from-the-command-line/) . There maybe something wrong with your `build.stagingDirectory`. Double check this, if your `build.stagingDirectory` is too long and too bloated. The package location of folder structure must be the same.

Comment: @CaptainKirk Moreover you could also give a try with changing `/p:PackageLocation` to `/p:PackageLocation="$(BuildConfiguration)`"such as mentioned in this link:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33904574/using-visual-studio-team-services-to-build-a-solution-containing-multiple-web-ap

Comment: @CaptainKirk Just like *Eddie* suggested, you should use other argument instead of `$(build.stagingDirectory)` in package location.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this arguments:

```
/p:outdir="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\DeployPackages"
```