# How to customize "ASP.NET CORE (Full framework)" build definition template for a solution with multiple web apps and deploy each on Azure

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-devops, visual-studio-2017, devops

I have a solution with 4 Asp.Net Core (full framework) web apps inside. How can you create the structure of the Artifacts Explorer shown in the image posted 
 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33904574/using-visual-studio-team-services-to-build-a-solution-containing-multiple-web-ap#) by Donovan Brown if you create a new Build Definition using the VSO template "ASP.NET CORE (.NET Framework).

The template contains a Visual Studio Build (version 1*)  task with MSBuildArguments "/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:DesktopBuildPackageLocation="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\WebApp.zip" /p:DeployIisAppPath="Default Web Site" "

This creates a single WebApp.zip with all the web apps in the solution.

I want to have a zip file for every web app in the solution so that I can create Release definitions for each web app using the Azure deployment teamplate.

Thank you

Comment: `PackageAsSingleFile=true` ? maybe set it to `false`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create packages of web apps by using publish profiles with the same name.

1. Right click the project > Publish >Create a publish profile (Custom)
2. Select **Web Deploy Package**
3. Specify **relative path** in Package location (e.g. `..\..\a\Web1`)
4. Other settings
5. After that, you can specify **/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile="[profile name]"** in MSBuild Arguments of Visual Studio Build task.

Comment: Thank you. It works but you have to change the Package Location to "d:\a\1\a\Web1.zip" since Team services Online throws error when giving a relative path. Anyway I was wondering if there is any another way without putting a publish profile under git.